# setting environmental variable in windows using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

To start the my project in windows i have to set the java environmental variable in cmd using below command

```
set JAVA_HOME = D:\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

but it didn't set the environment variable, i don't know what the issue.After pending couple hours i find the reason that is due to white space on both side of **=** symbol.Because of this environmental variable not getting set and i changed by command to

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

after that it is working fine.

My question is why this both command are not equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set` command is aware of spaces. When you issue the command

```
set JAVA_HOME = D:\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

you actually set the variable `JAVA_HOME␣` to value `␣D:\Java\jdk1.7.0`. Note the spaces: `␣`!

You can check it using the following way:

```
> echo [%JAVA_HOME%]
[%JAVA_HOME%]
> echo [%JAVA_HOME %]
[ D:\Java\jdk1.7.0]
```

The brackets are included in order to highlight spaces, they are not important by themselves.

Comment: Being able to put spaces in the variable name isn't very useful, but has to remain possible for backwards compatibility.  On the other hand, it is important to be able to put spaces in the variable value.